# How to get file name,size using C#?

Tags: c#

Trying to get the size of the folder in given directory, for that i written code. It is throwing error at Directory. Help to find the problem. This is my code

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("File Size");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Size");

        string[] folderPaths = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Save\");
        long b = 0;
       foreach (string s in folderPaths)
        {
            string[] a = Directory.GetFiles(s, "*.*");
            foreach (string name in a)
             {
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(name);
                b += info.Length;
              } 
             var row = dt.NewRow();  
             row["Name"] = s.Remove(0, s.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
             row["Size"] = b.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
     // here dt contain the data in table format with column Name,Size
```

Comment: It would be useful to *show* us the error.

Comment: Could not find a part of the path

Comment: @Suryasasidhar: Debug your code and check  which line shows you the error, and what would be the value at that time etc. Which may help you to solve the issues

Comment: If the Exception is occurring at `Directory.GetDirectories`, the error `Could not find a part of the path` would suggest that `C:\Save` doesn't exist, or you don't have permission to access it.

Comment: Yeah , our production people given this path, when i ask the same to them they inform me that they deleted that.

Comment: As @James suggested it can be a permission issue, run your visual studio "as administrator" and run your code again if you are sure the path is correct and you can open it via file explorer.

Comment: I can see some more issues: are you sure, that all subdirectories consist of files only? You might want to use some recursive function. Also, good practice would be to check if directory exists before working with it.

Comment: Debug your code and check array folderPaths  . Does it contain value as valid paths ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Directory exists? 
Also there is a bug in your code because b is never reset, so each folder has it's size + previous size.

Personally I would use:

```
    public long GetDirSize(DirectoryInfo dir, bool includeSubfolders)
    {
        if (!dir.Exists) return 0;
        return dir.GetFiles("*.*", includeSubfolders ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Sum(x => x.Length);
    }
```

Full code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("File Size");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Size");// could be dt.Columns.Add("Size", typeof(long))
DirectoryInfo save = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Save\");
if (save.Exists)
{
    foreach (var dir in save.GetDirectories())
    {
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        row["Name"] = dir.FullName.TrimEnd('\\');
        // If you want to count also files in subfolders cahnge false to true 
        // If you add column with long type, calling ToString() will not be necessary
        row["Size"] = GetDirSize(dir, false);
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }    
}
```